# Changing scrollview overscroll rebound speed

Tags: java, android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scrollview with overscroll enabled. When the user overscrolls the list it rebounds back to the end of the list like so:

```
    @Override
protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,   int scrollY,
                               int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX,
                               int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {
    return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY,
            mMaxXOverscrollDistance, maxOverScrollY, isTouchEvent);

}
```

where mMaxXOverscrollDistance is whatever distance I want to allow overscrolling. How can I control speed of the rebound? I want it to rebound back to the body of the list faster than the default speed.